# NullPointerException in collection.insert() MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

Well, I'm a beginner with MongoDB, so I tried to change getDB() to getDatabase() and I got null in
this line => this.col.insert(doc);

could Someone help me with this?

```
public class MongoDBPersonDAOnew {

    private DBCollection col;
    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MongoDBPersonDAOnew(MongoClient mongo) {
        
        
        MongoCollection<Document> col =  mongo.getDatabase("journaldev").getCollection("Persons");      
        
        System.out.println(col +" teste01"); 
        //com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl@47bccada teste01
        
    }

    public Person createPerson(Person p) {
        
        System.out.println(p.getName() + " teste02");
        DBObject doc = PersonConverter.toDBObject(p);
        System.out.println(doc +" teste03");
        //this.col.insert(doc);
        this.col.insert(doc);
        System.out.println(col);
        ObjectId id = (ObjectId) doc.get("_id");
        p.setId(id.toString());
        System.out.println(p +" teste04");
        //com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl@5be01b45 teste01
```

return  p;
}

```
    INFO: Server startup in 4443 ms
    com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl@29f80582 teste01
yy teste02
{"name": "yy", "country": "uu"} teste03
    dez 11, 2021 10:24:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.AddPersonServletnew] in context with path [/MongoDBWebapp] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dao.MongoDBPersonDAOnew.createPerson(MongoDBPersonDAOnew.java:45)
        at servlets.AddPersonServletnew.doPost(AddPersonServletnew.java:40)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```

Comment: `MongoCollection<Document> col =  mongo.getDatabase…` ← This declares a *brand new variable* named `col`.  The private `col` field of your class will never be set, so it remains null.  Solution:  Remove `MongoCollection<Document>` from that line.  Just write `col =  mongo.getDatabase` …

Comment: Hi,  I tried that, but  this line became red mongo.getDatabase("journaldev").getCollection("Persons");
and asks fo cast with (DBCollection)

or change col for type of col to MongoCollection<Document>

both ways iis not successful

Comment: I take this example 
https://www.journaldev.com/4011/mongodb-java-servlet-web-application-example-tutorial
and worked fine but getDB() was deprecated

Comment: I tried but mongo.getDatabase("journaldev").getCollection("Persons"); became red, asking for cast with DBCollection or change col to MongoCollection<Document>

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I meant that you probably want to change `private DBCollection col;` to `private MongoCollection<Document> col;`.

Comment: don't worry.

I tried changing  private MongoCollection<Document> col 
but insert(doc) ,  col.remove(query), col.findOne(query);  col.update(query,  became red 

he method insert(DBObject) is undefined for the type MongoCollection<Document>